# Android drawArc irregular shape

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I am drawing two arc one over the other to show progress. But when the arc is 50% it is showing like above.

```
<code>
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawArc(mArcRect, 135, 270, false, mArcPaint);
    canvas.drawArc(mArcRect, 135, 135, false,
                mProgressPaint);
    //canvas.drawArc(mArcRect, 135, 130, false, mProgressPaint);
}
</code>
```

But when i draw arc with sweep angle as 130 degree for the progress arc it is drawing smoothly.[image]
[image]